# Current induced on a transmisison line

Tags: current-measurement, emc, pcb-antenna, microstrip

[image]I have a micro-strip transmission line as shown in the figure which is incident by an external EM field. This field will induce some voltage and current on it. I want to measure the induced voltage and current. Induced voltage can be measured using a DSO across the transmission line and the ground plane. Can it be possible to measure the induced current? The frequency of induced EM field is in a range of 500MHz to 1GHz.

Comment: does your DSO have 50 ohm Zin? how will 50 ohms affect the field? if you don't load the micro-strip, it can simply be a high-Q resonator. What is important to you?

Comment: are you talking about a PCB, is there any other traces on that PCB other than Microstrip trace u r referring. Any other sources in PCB. do u control on the amount of External EM field incident on trace.

Comment: What does your micro-strip look like? Is it straight or meandering? What is the length?

Comment: Current isn't induced; voltage is induced. Current may flow but that depends on the loading circuit.

Comment: @mohitsingh please modify your question and show a schematic and some information (like dimensions of the microstrip)

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Yes DSO has 50 ohms Zin. I am loading the line with 50 ohms impedance.

Comment: @user19579 , Yes, I can control the power of external EM field. Ther are no any other traces on the PCB, I have added a reference figure with the question.

Comment: @EasyOhm The reference figure is added with the question, the length of transmission line is 15cm.

Comment: @Andyaka , In the book Analysis of Multiconductor Transmission Lines by Clayton R. Paul, in chapter 11 it gives an equation for both induced voltage and current on a transmission line in an external field.

Comment: @VoltageSpike I have added a reference diagram with the question. The length of transmission line is 15cm.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the microstrip line as an capacitor, with whatever is radiating as one plate and the microstrip line forming the other side of the plate (and negliect fringe fields, especially if you put the radiator close). If you could estimate the capacitance. And then the capacitance between the microstrip line and ground, you could model the noise.

Or if you wanted to measure it experimentally  you could turn off all voltage sources and connect and oscilloscope probe to the microstrip line and the ground of the oscilloscope to the ground of the PCB and measure the noise.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I have done the same to measure the induced/noise voltage. But the book Analysis of Multiconductor Transmission Lines by Clayton R. Paul, in chapter 11 it gives equations for both induced voltage and current on a transmission line in an external field. The above method can be used to measure induced voltage. How can I measure induced current experimentally?